# Can a gargoyle embrace animals?

Tags: world-of-darkness, vampire-the-masquerade, vampire-the-dark-ages

One of my players is playing a gargoyle. He says that his character can embrace animals, but I can't confirm his claim. I've looked for these rules in *Vampire: Dark Ages, 20th Aniversary Edition* and *Vampire: The Masquerade, 20th Aniversary Edition*, but I've not found anything.

According to [this wiki](http://whitewolf.wikia.com/wiki/Embrace_(VTM)), it's impossible to embrace animals, but it doesn't refer the books, so I don't know if it's accurate or if there's a gargoyles exception somewhere.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As you point out, animals cannot be embraced, barring the unusual case of the [Aabbt Kindred](http://whitewolf.wikia.com/wiki/Aabbt_Kindred), where one Setite NPC from a 1e sourcebook somehow managed to turn her cobras into vampires. The rules don't permit it. The Tremere do have rituals to create servitors that could resemble a gargoyle-Embraced animal, although it would have an animal's intelligence at best.

Comment: Is there a reason the gargoyle player would believe his character capable of this *beyond* those wacky *1e* vampire cobras? Like a short story or illustration or *something?* (It just seems such a strange thing to believe, to be sitting around the table and burst out with *O, yeah, well the rules say somewhere that gargoyles can make vampire squirrels!* or whatever.) I'm totally cool with this being all there is, by the way.

Comment: @HeyICanChan It's possible that, having seen depictions of small, gargoyle-like creatures, the player presumed they had to come from Embraced animals. It could be that, under the assumption that you can feed from animals and ghoul animals, making them into vampires seemed a logical progression. Maybe he just wants a flying rock kitty Retainer.

Comment: @HeyICanChan ... I have to say that it was like that. He just said that he can, and tried it, but with a scorpion... The result was a dead scorpion just because YOU CAN'T BITE GENTLY A SCORPION WITH FOUR POTENCE POINTS AND FIVE STRENGHT POINTS! It was funny, at least

Comment: @SliferDragon Even if you could, since you can't feed productively on insects, spiders, or other arthropods, I question how one would even start the process. Yeah, looks like one for the "weird things players do" file.

Answer (score 5):

I know this is years late, but in the 1st Edition Dark Ages Book of Storyteller Secrets there was a ritual Soul of the Earth that allowed a Gargoyle to Embrace an animal.